# Java classpath - one jar accessible, other not. Why?

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, classpath, weka

I'm trying to include a weka-src.jar file in Netbeans project and use it.

I already have set up my CLASSPATH and included :
`C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\weka-src.jar` into it

My JAVA_HOME variable is set to:
`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin`

but still I get the error in Netbeans: package doesn't exist and NetBeans doesn't auto-complete when I'm trying to add it to imports

Similar to this I jave a jar file 
`C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar`
also included in CLASSPATH and after adding to project Netbeans does the auto-complete thing.

My cmd:

```
echo %CLASSPATH%:
.;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext\weka-src.jar
```

Tried in Eclipse, the import part is not underlined, but still I can't use the classes, as if weka-src.jar wasn't even added

I can't figure out what is wrong. Any hints, please?
Maybe there is someone who can test it in his environment? weka-src.jar is in Weka's program files folder.

Comment: I'm not familiar - but `weka-src.jar` sounds like it contains sources and not compiled `.class` files - can that be the case?

Comment: **Please** format your question(s) as legibly as possible. I've done some minimal stuff with my edit, but I didn't want to change the meaning of anything. Refer to the handy **How to Format** box to the right of the question area, and [the page linked](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) from the **[?]** just above the question area.

Answer (score 3):

I am guessing that weka-src.jar contains source code which need to be compiled before it can be used.  Perhaps there is a weka.jar which has the compiled classes in it.

Comment: Voted up, -src jars contain source code, not compiled code so it's a waste of time adding them to a classpath.

Comment: Yes, but I need the source to make changes. There is weka.jar with *.class files in there, but I don't need that. Aha, so in libraries, there can be only *.class files?

Comment: weka-src.jar indeed contains source files. I suggest that you extract these into a source directory (actually a directory hierarchy) and add the sources to your own in a netbeans project.

Comment: If you need to change the source you need to unpack the Java files and compile them.

Answer (score 0):

In netbeans, you don't make classpath with windows environments variables, but with netbeans.

In netbeans right clic on your project node in window projects, choose *Properties*, and in properties *Librairies*. Add your jar.project/librairies with that.

Comment: I have it there as well, but still nothing: [screen from netbeans](http://i.imgur.com/C99vC.png)

Comment: In the libraries put the jar file with class files in it, not source file. The weka-src.jar contains java files, is there a weka-??.jar with classes inside it ?

Comment: yes, there is weka.jar with .class files but can I have in library .java files?

Comment: Yes, but it's not a solution. I think the Yuval's comments is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Istao is correct. For NB you need to add jars via Properties